# OpenVPN Bridged

Tags: ubuntu, openvpn

I have a VPS running on DigitalOcean and I'm trying to setup a bridged OpenVPN network, So far I've not managed to get it to work as the VPN only redirects traffic and doesn't allow communication as a "Network"..

The way I want my network to work is as follows in the image:
[image]

I've tried following tutorials from the OpenVPN website, they are very open-ended or not complete. Or when I do try and start bridging br0 and eth0 together, The entire network goes offline and I can't SSH into the box to do anything else.

Basically I want to get the openVPN bridge mode VPN working, And all the tutorials I have followed haven't worked as they are incomplete.

Comment: Why bridged?  This is not the best topology.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `eth0` to the existing `br0` bridge, not make a new bridge consisting of a physical device and an existing bridge.